# Bit Locker Keeps Pausing During Encryption

Tags: bitlocker

I am trying to encrypt a brand new Kingston 16 GB jump drive.  Bit Locker keeps pausing and then the program doesn't respond.  I click resume, which it does for a couple of seconds then goes back into pause mode.

Help???

Comment: IT'S OK!!  I formatted the drive and all is well.  Guess I should have done that first???

Comment: Nope...spoke too soon!  Made it to 2.8% then paused again.  When I resume it loads .1% then pauses again....frustrating....

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? I know some people on certain versions have had trouble with Windows automatically putting usb devices to sleep when it shouldn't. For example, see  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/windows-81-causes-external-hard-drives-to-auto/c03b9212-9972-44b9-bfec-1cd7e70ec67e . You might also check event viewer to see if there are any messages from Bitlocker about why it paused or any messages about the drive being put to sleep or added/removed.